# free virtualbox vm of windows 8

Tags: macos, windows-8, virtualbox

As a web developer I've used the free vm's microsoft provide for testing (doctored and configured for [easy installation on Linux and OSX](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms) with virtualbox).

Does anyone know if there's an equivalent for Win8? (something that's been OK'd by Microsoft - not just a rip-off copy).

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I can think of off hand is the [windows 8 enterprise evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx) (which will run for 90 days before needing an install). Technet had the same for windows 7 I believe at one point.